# How to switch css based table column with nested content using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to switch the position of ul from left to the right using jquery. I am using table for the layout. I have few lines of code to do the job and it worked. The issue is that when I use it as a nested content, the ul section is doubled up. Please check my fiddle to understand what I mean and pls help me solve the issue. Thanks!
[FIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/umm10dqq/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tabs.vright > ul:eq(0)').appendTo('.tabs.vright');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is taking the first `.tabs.vright > ul` and appending it to ALL your `.tabs.vright`.

You need to loop through your elements and apply accordingly.

Like so:

```
$('.tabs.vright > ul').each(function() {
    $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/umm10dqq/2/)